# OpenFaces Composite Filter does not render the user search input text field

Tags: jsf, openfaces

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to use the composite filter but in vain. While we struggled the whole day trying to know that it does not work if the table contains a column with action buttons and no data type, now we are wondering why it does not render the text field for the user to type his filter criteria.

1. We click on the (+) button = A drop
   down with column names is rendered.
2. 2- From this dropdown, we choose a
   column.
3. 3- A 'NOT' checkbox and Another
   dropdown with expressions (equals,
   contains...etc) is rendered.
4. 4- We choose an expression from the
   list.

   5- The input text field supposed to be rendered is not rendered at all.
   Which makes the composite filter non usable as the user cannot type his search criteria!

   Please help.

   ```
          <div>
        <h:form>
                   <o:compositeFilter id="bookfilter"  for="bookstable" autoDetect="true"/>
                       <o:dataTable id="bookstable" sortColumnId="title" value="#{bookController.items}" var="item" >
                           <o:singleRowSelection />

                           <f:facet name="header">
                               Book TABLE
                           </f:facet>
                           <f:facet name="columnMenu">
                               <o:columnMenu/>
                           </f:facet>
                           <o:column id="title" sortingExpression="#{item.title}" header="title">
                               <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
                           </o:column>
                           <o:column id="topic" header="topic">
                               <h:outputText value="#{item.topic}"/>
                           </o:column>
                           <o:column id="writer" header="writerid" >
                               <h:outputText value="#{item.writer}"/>
                           </o:column>

                       </o:dataTable>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently It is a bug affecting versions of Mojarra ulterior to 2.0.3 (2.0.4+).
http://requests.openfaces.org/browse/OF-81
And not fixed yet in the nightly builds.